# Non-Ashkenazic Talmud-learning tune

Tags: torah-study, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, music, yemenite-temani

I am very familiar with a particular Ashkenazi yeshivish tune for Talmud learning.  This is well-described in the linked question as:

> [T]he kind of singing rhythm that people use when contrasting two different points. Usually it starts on a high note and continues monotonically until the end of the sentence, and then dips slightly. Then, the same thing happens in the second sentence, but with a bigger dip at the end. Usually the first word is "if" and is emphasized heavily. This tune is also often accompanied by a hand gesture where the speaker makes a dipping motion with his thumb.
>
> "IF we're holding with some random position in this debate, then we have a CONsequence. BUT IIIIIFFF we hold this other position, then the consequence is dif-erent."

One answer there says that [the concept of a tune for Mishnah study is mentioned in the Talmud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28218/1498), so it predates Ashkenazim.  On [further research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#Mishnah), it seems that there was once an actual trope system used for the Mishnah.<sup>1</sup>

Is the same tune used in traditional non-Ashkenazi <strike>yeshivahs</strike> yeshivot?  If not, what tune(s) do Sephardim use?  What tune(s) do Mizrachim use?  Is there another Ashkenazic tune tradition?

<sup>1</sup> Not sure how applicable [this ogg file of "Amar Rabbi Elazar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Omar_Rabbi_Elozor.ogg) is, but it exists.

---

Inspired by: [Where did the sing-song chant that Jews often use while contrasting points come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/where-did-the-sing-song-chant-that-jews-often-use-while-contrasting-points-come)

Answer (score 5):

Some of the traditional Mishna recitation tunes of the Edot HaMizrach can be found on the website of Mishna Sedura at http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/

For example:

http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/files/megillaA.mp3 by Rabbi Yitzchak Sharvit according to his original adaptation of modern punctuation to Sephardic tradition.

http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/files/berajot_perek1.mp3 by Reb Mordechai Sayed, according to the Syrian Halabi tradition.

Comment: This is great!  Brachot sounds like it uses the Mishnah trope mentioned in the question.  Is that true? Do mizrachis use a similar trope setting for Talmud or is this exclusively mishna?

Comment: Btw, any mishna tune that includes a harmonica is fantastic as far as I'm concerned :)

Comment: I'm 99% sure that Berachot Perek Alef file is a recording of Hagaon Harav Meir Mazuz.

Answer (score 3):

The Italian tradition for reciting the Mishnah is now almost lost but it survives in the tunes of the rabbinical parts of the Pessach seder. In [this multimedial haggadah](http://www.archivio-torah.it/feste/pesach/haggadot/audio/audiohaggada.pdf) you can hear it by clicking on the musical note symbol. An example is [this](http://www.archivio-torah.it/feste/pesach/haggadot/audio/42.mp3).